# In netty, is it ok to pass a pooled ByteBuf to another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I'm using netty 4.10beta6.

In channel A, I read a `ByteBuf` by overriding `channelRead()`(which uses a pooled buf allocator by default), consume&release the buf in channel B by passing it to `channelB.write(buf)`, where channel B's eventloop is in a different thread. Is this OK?

I ask because I partly read the source of `PooledByteBufAllocator`, it uses thread local cache which seems not suppose to work across threads.

I made small tests it works fine, want make sure if it lasts for long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is fine to pass between threads as long as you not call read/write/set/get etc methods concurrently.

Comment: Hi, @Norman Maurer, in my case, i pass content-filled bytebuf created by shared pooled allocator from current thread, then read/close the bytebuf in another thread. netty sometimes throws exception: `io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0`. which means the pooled allocator give me a bytebuf  already deallocated. how can i fix this?